# spark - contiue job processing after tasks failure

Tags: apache-spark, configuration, pyspark

Is there a way to tell spark to continue a job after a single task failed?

Or even better:
Can we configure a job to fail only if a certain percent of the tasks fails?

My scenario is like this:
I'm using pyspark to do some parallel computations.
I have a job that is composed from thousands of tasks (which are more or less independent from each other - i can allow some to fail).
1 task fails (throws exception), and after few retries for this task the entire job is aborted.

Is there a way to change this (weird) behavior?

Comment: What exceptions are thrown? I'm thinking that if you know that some tasks may fail, you can write your spark code to handle this. Tasks should only fail when something is very wrong - like if you are using too much memory for instance.

Comment: This is what I'm going to do. The exceptions that are thrown are coming as a result of bugs (of other programmers :-)) 
I prefer that the infrastructure will handle this and not me, since failed tasks can be shown in the UI etc.
I guess i have no choice but catch the exceptions myself and deal with this progrematically.

Comment: I don't think relying on the cluster to handle known/unknown bugs is a good idea. There would be no guarantee of the correctness of the result.

Comment: Throwing exception is a way to say that " i have a failure" - the cluster should handle this - show it in the ui etc.
Not all excpetions means bugs - some may indicate that the data is not good - My data come from physical signals.
I now have to collect the failures myself and display it when the processing ends - which is something the cluster should provide.

Implementing thresholds for taks failures should also be provided by the cluster - like in hadoop.

Comment: Also, consider a use case where the spark batch job runs dozens of peoples code - you want to allow people to fail their tasks without implementing a fancy code infrastructure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in spark.
There is an open jira ticket([SPARK-10781](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10781)) for it but I don't see any action there.

You can do it in mapreduce using config `mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent and mapreduce.max.reduce.failures.percent`

Comment: wow - that is unbelivable. Its almost a show stopper for me with spark.
It's a big - no no thing.

Comment: Also, mapreduce is not an option for me. I'm building an infra to python developers who knows nothing about Java

Comment: The configuration spark.task.maxFailures is 4 by default it means failed tasks will be retried 4 times then they will be marked as failures.You can increase the value of this configuration to may be 8 so that your other tasks of job which can finish successfully can continue before the job is failed.