# Can spark ignore the a task failure due to an account data issue and continue the job process for other accounts?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

I want spark to ignore some failed tasks due to data issues. Also, I want spark not to stop the whole job due to some insert failures.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013893/spark-contiue-job-processing-after-tasks-failure

Answer (score 0):

if you are using databricks, you can handle bad records and files as explained in this article.
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/handling-bad-records.html

From the documentation:

> Databricks provides a unified interface for handling bad records and
> files without interrupting Spark jobs. You can obtain the exception
> records/files and reasons from the exception logs by setting the data
> source option badRecordsPath. badRecordsPath specifies a path to store
> exception files for recording the information about bad records for
> CSV and JSON sources and bad files for all the file-based built-in
> sources (for example, Parquet).

You can also use some data cleansing library like Pandas,Optimus, sparkling.data,spark vanilla, dora etc. That will give you an insight into the bad data and let you fix your data before running analysis on it.